# What is present time in Turkey

Tags: word-usage

(1) It was Anatolia, what is present time in Turkey.

(2) It was Anatolia, what is present time Turkey.

Which of the two is correct?  Could you help me clarify it?

My real question is if I can use an what-clause to be an apposition to a noun with a comma before the what-clause.

What I’m trying to say is:

> Called Asia Minor (Lesser Asia) by the Romans, Anatolia is the Asian part of ancient Turkey.

I really would to know if I can use an what-clause to be an apposition to the noun *Anatolia*.

Answer (score 2):

I think a fitting expression for what you are saying is “modern day”:

> It was Anatolia – what is now **modern day** Turkey.

The word *modern* is often used in this context. For example, the New World Encyclopedia reads:

> The History of Anatolia encompasses the region known as Anatolia, known by the Latin name of Asia Minor, considered to be the westernmost extent of Western Asia. Geographically it **encompasses what is most of modern Turkey**, from the Aegean Sea to the mountains on the Armenian border to east and by the Black Sea and the Taurus mountains from north to south.

I’ve also seen the phrase “present day” used; for example, and recent [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/researchers-identify-present-day-turkey-as-origin-of-indo-european-languages/2012/08/23/6133c564-ed3e-11e1-b09d-07d971dee30a_story.html?utm_term=.79f86c714120) article was headlined:

> Researchers identify **present day Turkey** as origin of Indo-European languages

One other expression you might see used is “currently known as”. For example, a [2008 book](https://books.google.com/books?id=U7xwaYoK7UsC) reads:

> The predecessor to the **modern** Turkish Republic was the Ottoman Empire which ruled the territory **currently known as Turkey** until the Turkish Republic was formally established in 1923.

Comment: Except Anatolia is not modern day Turkey. It's just part of it; it's in modern day Turkey.

Comment: @Lambie - Fair point, but my answer is meant to highlight grammar, not history and geography. The sentences could be modified as needed, e.g.: _It was Anatolia – overlapping most of what is now modern day Turkey_, (or _contained in what is now modern day Turkey,_ etc.)